# How to specify install location of additional files during the creation of module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have published a module to pypi called 'surrealism' that generates surreal sentences and error messages.  It contains a SQLite3 database containing all of the words and sentences needed for my module.

All of the following install methods work fine:

> python setup.py install
>
> pip install surrealism
>
> easy_install surrealism

and the module works fine.

However, when installing into a virtualenv, things go wrong.  surrealism.py get installed into **C:\Users\me\virtualenvs\surrealism\Lib\site-packages**, but **surrealism.sqlite** doesn't get installed?

If I run python and try and import the module, my module creates a new sqlite3 database called **surrealism.sqlite** at **C:\Users\me\virtualenvs\surrealism**

The contents of my setup.py follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup

long_desc = open('readme.rst').read()

setup(name = 'surrealism',
      version = '0.5.2',
      py_modules = ['surrealism'],
      author = 'Morrolan',
      author_email = 'morrolan@icloud.com',
      url = 'https://github.com/Morrolan/surrealism',
      license = 'GNU General Public License (GPL)',
      description = 'Surreal sentence and error message generator.',
      long_description = long_desc,
      platforms = ['Windows','Unix','OS X'],
      download_url = "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/surrealism/",
      keywords = ["surreal", "surrealism", "error message"],
      classifiers = [
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3",
        "Development Status :: 4 - Beta",
        "Environment :: Other Environment",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "Intended Audience :: Education",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License (GPL)",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
        "Topic :: Education",
        "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules",
         ],
      install_requires=['setuptools'],
      
      )
```

In surrealism.py, I reference/connect to the SQLite3 database in a fairly rudimentary way:

```
CONN = sqlite3.connect('surrealism.sqlite')
```

But so far it hasn't caused me any problems.

is there a more explicit way to reference surrealism.sqlite, or do I have to specify something in setup.py to force the installation?

Kind Regards,
Morrolan

Comment: you can set a path to the database otherwise it will be created where surrealism.py runs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the crucial problem is exactly the way you are connecting to your sqlite database; That will refer to a file in the *current* directory;, anywhere the program that invokes it is trying to run.  What you want to say is

```
... sqlite3.connect(where_this_python_lib_is_installed + '...sqlite')
```

So that it doesn't matter where it's installed.  There is a fairly standard way to do that, using the [`pkg_resources`](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/pkg_resources.html) library.  Since we're trying to discover a sqlite database, that means we need a real file on disk, not a string or file-like object; so the right method to use here `pkg_resources.resource_filename`, we just need to change the connect call to:

```
from pkg_resources import resource_filename
CONN = sqlite3.connect(resource_filename(__name__, 'surrealism.sqlite'))
```

But wait... That only works if the package data is in a *package*, but you currently have a *module*.  Not a big problem, though; we'll rename `surrealism.py` to `surrealism/__init__.py`, `surrealism.sqlite` to `surrealism/surrealism.sqlite`, and make the appropriate changes in `MANIFEST.in`.  We'll also need to tell setuptools about this.  Change `py_modules=["surrealism"],` in your setup.py to `packages=["surrealism"]`.

Almost there,  The last thing we need to do is get setuptools to actually *install* that file from source.  The first is pretty obvious, we need to tell it which files to copy; Add

```
package_data={'surrealism': ['surrealism.sqlite']},
```

To your `setup.py`, the second change is more subtle.  In most cases, `setuptools` tries to install packages as zip files.  This is usually a good thing; but in our case, we need to pass the filename of a real file to `sqlite.connect`, so we have to tell it not to try to zip the package.  For that, just add

```
zip_safe=False,
```

To your setup.py.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.

I have tried what you suggested and it has worked perfectly.  Thankyou so much.